# Statistics probability in blackjack

Tags: probability

If the probability of winning at blackjack is .45, each bet is \$2 and you get \$2 if you win, what is the expected number of wins and how much money do you expect to lose if you play 300 times?

expected number of wins: (.45)(300) = 135
expected loss: .45*2+0.55*−2 = -.2

Does this seem right? I think number of wins looks right, but not expected loss.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected number of wins is correct.  As for the expected loss, what you calculated is the expected loss *for a single play*.  For $300$ such plays, the expected loss is $300$ times the value you calculated for a single play.

Comment: right, I realized that. I got -60

Comment: @Will As an instructive exercise, can you calculate the **variance** of (a) the number of wins in $300$ plays, and (b) the amount of loss in $300$ plays?

Comment: Is anyone familiar with R programming? I need to enter this into R, but I'm not sure of a function that will calculate this

Comment: Amount of losses in 300 plays is 165